# SwiftUI .fullScreenCover appears as a .sheet

Tags: swiftui

I expected to be able to dismiss a sheet and present a fullScreenCover straight after, however this doesn't seem to work without a delay between the two state modifications.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var sheet = false
    @State var cover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Click me for sheet") {
            sheet = true
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $cover) {
            Text("This is a full screen cover")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheet) {
            Text("This is a sheet")
            Button("This doesn't work") {
                sheet = false
                cover = true
            }
            Button("This works") {
                sheet = false
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                    cover = true
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Clicking the "This doesn't work" button produces the below image demonstrating a fullScreen cover displaying as a sheet and not covering the entire screen:

Introducing a small delay between the two state modifications which is done by clicking the "This works" button fixes the issue.

What am I not understanding about SwiftUI here that would explain this behaviour?

[image]

Tested on:

- Xcode 12.5.1
- iPhone 12 Pro Max Simulator running iOS 14.5

Adding the modifiers to seperate view like this also doesn't work:

`Text("Another view").sheet(isPresented: $sheet) { ...`

Comment: Same issue.... what on earth is going on here?

Comment: Using `Task.detached(priority: .background)` also seems to fix it but not `Task` nor `Task.detached(priority: .userInitiated)`. Seems like a timing issue??

Answer (score 1):

you could try this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var sheet = false
    @State var cover = false
    
    var body: some View {
        Button("Click me for sheet") {
            sheet = true
        }
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $cover) {
            Text("This is a full screen cover")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $sheet, onDismiss: {cover = true}) {
            Text("This is a sheet")
        } 
    }
}
```